# comp fazer que uma variavel de um banco de dados tenha o total de cadastros que um outro banco possui?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, aplicação-web, django-templates

opa, me chamo antonio, estou iniciando em django, estou criando uma aplicação onde eu preciso que o atributo totmatérias da tabela "Escritor" tenha o numero de noticias escritas por aquele escritor que está guardada na outra tabela, alguma ajuda? segue o código:

```
from datetime import datetime
from django.utils import timezone
from django.db import models
from django.db.models.fields import CharField, DateField

class Noticias(models.Model):
    titulo = models.CharField(max_length=30, help_text='maximo: 30 caracteres')
    data = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)
    editado = models.DateField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False)
    escritor = models.ForeignKey('Escritor', on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    texto = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    resumo = models.CharField(max_length=100, help_text='Um breve resumo da matéria principal, de no maximo 100 caracteres.')

    def __str__(self): return f'{self.titulo} - {self.data}'

class Escritor(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    nome = models.CharField(max_length=50, help_text='maximo 50 caracteres')
    totmatérias = ???
    nascimento = DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)
    cidadeNatal = CharField(max_length=40, help_text='cidade onde voce nasceu')

    def __str__(self): return f'{self.id} - {self.nome}'
```

como visto no código, eu quero que, na classe Escritor, na variavel totmatérias contenha o total de matérias escritas pelo mesmo escritor que estão na classe matérias. Ex: se o escritor 1 registrou 5 matérias, eu quero que fique 5 no totmatérias desse escritor. Espero que tenha dado para entender, obrigado dsd já.

Answer (score 0):

Crie esse campo como integer:

```
totmatérias = models.IntegerField()
```

Na hora de voce popular essa tabela, voce faz a logica e manda o numero que deseja...

Voce pode sobrescrever o metodo save, para que, na hora de salvar, faça essa logica desejada:

```
class Escritor(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    totmatérias = models.IntegerField()
    ...

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        numero_total = Noticias.objects.filter(escritor=self.nome).count()
        self.totmatérias = numero_total
        return super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Esse código acima serve apenas para referencia.. Depende muito do que exatamente voce precisa. Nao deve funcionar dessa exata maneira..
Se quiser testar a logica e ir mandando possiveis erros, podemos ir ajustando.

Comment: obrigado pela ajuda, irei testar